# Rating Algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm, rating

I'm trying to develop a rating system for an application I'm working on. Basically app allows you to rate an **object** from 1 to 5(represented by stars). But I of course know that keeping a rating count and adding the rating the number itself is **not** feasible.

So the first thing that came up in my mind was **dividing the received rating by the total ratings given.** Like if the object has received the rating 2 from a user and if the number of times that object has been rated is 100 maybe adding the 2/100. However I believe this method is not good enough since 1)A naive approach 2) In order for me to get the number of times that object has been rated I have to do a look up on db which might end up having time complexity O(n)

So I was wondering what alternative and possibly **better** ways to approach this problem?

Comment: If you want to prevent rating more than once per user, or letting someone change the rating, you might wanna just store the `person_id product_id rating`. You haven't specified functional needs, which makes an answer difficult to judge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep in DB 2 additional values - number of times it was rated and total sum of all ratings. This way to update object's rating you need only to:

1. Add new rating to total sum.
2. Divide total sum by total times it was rated.

Comment: You are definitely right. I might end up trying it. But I was also wondering if a **better** rating system could be applied, with a different method.

Comment: There are **other** rating systems, but none of them was ever considered as a single best rating system :) If you give more details about your application, maybe I'll be able to propose some other options that could fit better for your particular case.

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches to this but before that check

1. If all feedback givers treated at equal or some have more weight than others (like panel review, etc)
2. If the objective is to provide only an average or any score band or such. Consider scenario like this website - showing total reputation score
3. And yes - if average is to be omputed, you need to have total and count of feedback and then have to compute it - that's plain maths. But if you need any other method, be prepared for more compute cycles. balance between database hits and compute cycle but that's next stage of design. First get your requirement and approach to solution in place.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should keep separate counters for 1 stars, 2 stars, ... to calcuate the rating, you'd have to compute `rating = (1*numOneStars+2*numTwoStars+3*numThreeStars+4*numFourStars+5*numFiveStars)/numOneStars+numTwoStars+numThreeStars+numFourStars+numFiveStars)`

This way you can, like amazon also show how many ppl voted 1 stars and how many voted 5 stars...

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a vote up/down mechanism over numbers of stars? It doesn't directly solve your problem but it's worth noting that other sites such as YouTube, Facebook, StackOverflow etc all use +/- voting as it is often much more effective than star based ratings.